# How to register new attribute with Forio-Epicenter Flow.js

Tags: forio-contour

I am trying to register a new attribute as shown in the webinar at Youtube.
I am using almost the exact example from the webinar. My HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ub-component="Button" data-ub-version="%package_version%" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%;" data-f-on-click="step(1)" data-f-toggle="Time">Advance By One Year</button>
```

My javascript:

```
Flow.dom.attributes.register('toggle', function (value) {(value>=2020)?this.CSS('display','none'):this.CSS('display',''block)});
```

When debugging via Chrome console, I noticed that "value" is always zero!

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I'm the lead developer on Flow.js and will be glad to take a look.  Can you post a link to your sim here?

Comment: This is a clean example of the problem: https://forio.com/app/ahmedg/smart-watch-example/

Comment: I added my script just before </body> tag. Here I use the example's original button and tie it with a new attribute 'toggle' referring to the 'Time' variable from the model with data-f-toggle="Time". I also added a new button and tied it with a new attribute 'datatoggle' referring to another variable from the model 'Historical Cumulative Profit' with data-f-datatoggle="Historical Cumulative Profit". In both cases I just try to log the value sent to the newly added attribute, which is always 0!